advice on statistical method
I just want some opinions on the best way to analyse some data as I am not very savy with statistics.
I have been collecting abundance data for microbes in soil. Gene copy numbers.
I have two forest types (Mixed species and bamboo) and two soil depths (10 cm and 50 cm).
My question is - Is anova appropriate here? As I only have two treatments rather than three?
I thought you needed more than two treatments for an ANOVA.
Best wishes

You need to tell us what you mean by "analyze:" what do you hope to learn from these data?

I want to find out if there is a difference between microbial abundance between depth and or treatments

For ANOVA, you need only 1 treatment, with more than 2 levels (1-way ANOVA), so you may have confused treatments, and levels. In your case, you have 2 treatments, each with 2 levels, and a 2-way ANOVA would be an appropriate test. In fact, you can run a 1-way ANOVA with 1 treatment, and 2 levels, and you just get the same results as a t-test. So really, ANOVA is at least 1 treatment, and at least 2 levels...
Of course, you need to check for departure from ANOVA's fundamental assumptions (independence, normality of residuals, homoscedasticity), and you need to check them "properly"; see various posts on CV with good discussions, e.g. here and here.
